# The result null.asInstanceOf[Int] is 0

Tags: scala

When I run `null.asInstanceOf[Int]`, I am surprised to find that the result is 0, I would ask why it is 0, I thought it should be null

Comment: If you thought that it should be 0, why you are surprised that it is 0?

Comment: @ThomasBöhm val test = null.asInstanceOf[Int], try that

Comment: @KamilBanaszczyk just tried it, now I can reproduce it. I deleted my comment.

Comment: Reread your question, Tom.

Comment: Update the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I thought it should be null

It can't be `null` because `Int` doesn't have a `null` value. You can see it if you try `null: Int` (type ascription instead of a cast), though the error message is ugly.

> why it is 0

Because it's defined this way in http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#the-null-value:

> > `asInstanceOf[T]` [on `null`] returns the default value of type `T`.

Interestingly, it used to be defined to throw `NullPointerException` instead, but actually implemented in the current way, so the specification was changed: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5236